# Android: How to get Bluetooth SDP record name?

Tags: android, bluetooth

In android, if I start listening using listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord, it asks to specify a UUID (which is fine), and also a name for the SDP record.

- Why do I need to provide a name?
- Can I from the client side when connecting to the socket get the SDP name?

Comment: It's a good question. If the name isn't important should we just use getName on the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You are making an SDP service record for the device, ie. Android wants to associate each UUID with a particular service or application, so the name should be your application name, eg `"com.example.bluetoothapp"`.